# How to resize images other than product images in magento

Tags: magento, image-resizing

Guys How can I Resize other images on fly like product images in magento??

I have created a module that receives user's profile picture & I want to resize them like magento product images.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you resize a product image it is using a `Varien_Image` behind the scenes, then it saves the image to file at the same time the URL is outputted. Since you will not be using a product image you'll need to call `Varien_Image->save($destination)` yourself.

If you need to look at how it works the code is in `/lib/Varien/Image.php` and `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent blog about this

http://subesh.com.np/2009/11/image-resize-magento-cache-resized-image/